# Python: Selenium to simulate onclick

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

I am trying to use python to play a simple javagame that I made for a class assignment. I am trying to make python open up a webpage and use the form buttons to input numbers.  I think this is close to what I need but I am not sure how to fix line 7

```
(li = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#button-one li:predict.input.value += 1'))

from selenium import webdriver

url = 'http://alexcassell.com/javagame'

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)
li = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#button-one li:predict.input.value += 1')
li.click()
```

Button-one is the ID of the first button.

Answer (score 1):

You CSS selector is not valid. Try this one instead:

```
li = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#button-five')
```

Note that you can get a CSS selector in your browser by inspecting the element and clicking on "Copy unique selector" in the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
li = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input#button-one[onclick="predict.input.value += 1"]')
```

or without element name "input":

```
li = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#button-one[onclick="predict.input.value += 1"]')
```

or if there is only element whose "id" is "button-one", simply write:

```
li = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#button-one')
```